# How to write a Serializable as the body of an http post request?

Tags: java, http-post, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a client-server app in which I have a `Serializable` class on both sides. I have to write an object of that class using `ObjectOutputStream` from the `client` and read it using `ObjectInputStream` on the server.

At the client I am using Apache `HttpClient` (version 4.2). I have to send the serializable object in an `HttpPost` request. How do I write the object to the `HttpPost` request in such a way that I can read it using `ObjectInputStream` at the server?

I am sending the request like this :

```
httpClient.execute(host,postRequest);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a [`BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.2.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/message/BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest.html) that contains a [`SerializableEntity`](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-4.2.x/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/SerializableEntity.html).

Basically, it would look something like this:

```
BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest postRequest = new BasicHttpEntityEnclosingRequest("POST", "uri");
postRequest.setEntity(new SerializableEntity(yourObject, false));
```

Comment: I have to read this serializable entity on the server side using `ObjectInputStream.readObject()`
I read that readObject() can be called successfully only if the object is written using writeObject(object)

Comment: That is what `SerializableEntity` does behind the scenes.